# Ajax functions not working in forms submitted

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, getjson

When my form is submitted, I want to, for example, get data from the server with $.getJson.

I wrote this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#websiteForm').submit(function (event) {
        $.getJSON('Home/checker', function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
})
```

My form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="websiteForm">
    <input type="text" name="txtWebsite" id="txtWebsite" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

But when I click to submit the form, nothing shows up.  I tested my `$.getJSON` function on page load, and it works well, so I don't know why this function is not working.

Comment: I'm not real familiar with mvc, but I know in asp.net it executes a doPostBack javascript function to submit which is different from actually submitting the form, so if mvc does the same thing, you may not be having that event actually fire. There are I believe event handlers you can tie onto that are built into the javascript which doPostBack would fire for you though I can't name them off hand.

Comment: you forgot to return false or prevent default in the submit handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace type submit by buttom.

```
    $(function () {
        $('button').click(function (event) {
            $.getJSON('Home/checker', function (data) {
                alert(data);
            });
        });
    })

<form action="" method="post" id="websiteForm">
<input type="text" name="txtWebsite" id="txtWebsite" />
<input type="button" name="button" />
</form>
```

or

```
$(function () {
        $('#websiteForm').submit(function (event) {
            $.getJSON('Home/checker', function (data) {
                alert(data);
            });
            return false;
        });
    })

<form action="" method="post" id="websiteForm">
<input type="text" name="txtWebsite" id="txtWebsite" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: The button is not really a good idea, since most browsers call the submit evvent when you press enter within one of the input fields

Comment: insert window.location = "url" after the alert. Ready, a submit.

Comment: @Ascension, what? please explain more?

Comment: @AmirHossein, if $.getJSON:success redirect the user for other page(window.location="url"). if $.getJSON:error alert the user with a message and no redirect.

Answer (score 2):

This should make it work

```
$(function () {
    $('#websiteForm').submit(function (event) {
        $.getJSON('Home/checker', function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

without `return false;` you submit the form (the page reloads) which stops the javascript